# How to make Alert Dialog shaking animation in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-alertdialog

I want to shake the alert dialog like this: (not only the text, but also the entire pop up dialog)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IaHMoifUBSw

How can I shake the whole alert dialog when user clicks a button?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done with `AnimatedBuilder` and `Transform` widgets. Use `sin` function from `dart:math` to map the `AnimationController` value between `0.0` to `1.0` into a smooth sinusoidal wave with desired amplitude. The period can be specified directly using `duration` in the `AnimationController` itself.

To start the animation, you can either call `controller.repeat()` to make it run indefinitely, until you call `controller.stop()`, or you can use `controller.forward()` to run it once.

To let it shake 3 times then stop, for example, you can do this:

```
onPressed: () async {
  await _controller.forward(from: 0.0);
  await _controller.forward(from: 0.0);
  await _controller.forward(from: 0.0);
},
```

This is how it looks in action (please bare with the frame rate limit of GIF):

[image: demo gif]

Full source code for you to use as a starting point is attached below. You can adjust `duration` and `distance` to change the intensity of the shaking animation:

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Test(),
    );
  }
}

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  const Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Shaking Dialog Demo')),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text('Show Dialog'),
          onPressed: () {
            showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (_) => ShakeableDialog(),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ShakeableDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  final Duration duration; // how fast to shake
  final double distance; // how far to shake

  const ShakeableDialog({
    Key? key,
    this.duration = const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
    this.distance = 24.0,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ShakeableDialogState createState() => _ShakeableDialogState();
}

class _ShakeableDialogState extends State<ShakeableDialog>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final _controller = AnimationController(
    vsync: this,
    duration: widget.duration,
  );

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _controller,
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
        final dx = sin(_controller.value * 2 * pi) * widget.distance;
        return Transform.translate(
          offset: Offset(dx, 0),
          child: child,
        );
      },
      child: AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Alert Dialog Title'),
        content: Text('Try these buttons!'),
        actions: [
          TextButton(
            child: Text('SHAKE 3 TIMES'),
            onPressed: () async {
              await _controller.forward(from: 0.0);
              await _controller.forward(from: 0.0);
              await _controller.forward(from: 0.0);
            },
          ),
          TextButton(
            child: Text('KEEP SHAKING'),
            onPressed: () => _controller.repeat(),
          ),
          TextButton(
            child: Text('STOP SHAKING'),
            onPressed: () => _controller.stop(),
          ),
          TextButton(
            child: Text('CLOSE'),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: One more question..
How can I block back button in Android?

Comment: @gurkanstack You can look into `WillPopScope` widget.